# Websocket subscription on base of attribute

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel

I am using `apache camel Websocket` for streaming stock prices. Currently it will stream all the prices for all the clients. This is wasting client bandwidth. They are only interested in some of the stocks prices.

I need a solution where a user can enter list of symbols during `websocket` subscription and my client will be publishing prices for all stock symbols but `camel websocket` should only show relevant prices to its client.

Comment: At this level of detail, this is not really a coding or code-design question.

Comment: this is coding question. it's kind of architecture question

Comment: if you control the server side then have the client ask a more more concise question to reduce traffic

Comment: But how i will identify client queries . if you can please give me some example. i would be really thankful